# Uncheck / deselect singleChoice ListView

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-listview, user-interaction

#### Combo - List with Option to Write In Unlisted Value

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/category_choices"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/other_please_specify"
        android:singleLine="true"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="326dp"/>
```

#### Data-Binding Works

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, categories);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
           selectedItem = (String) (listView.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
        }
});
```

#### How to Clear Radiobutton Selection When Any Text Entered in the EditText?

*I tried the following, but it does not work*

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            int checkedItem = listView.getCheckedItemPosition();
            listView.setItemChecked(checkedItem, false);
            selectedItem = null;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Whether KeyListener is invoking if you enter any text in Edit Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Text Watcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for Edit Text to listen for entered text :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
                         // do your stuffs here
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.e("TextWatcherTest", "afterTextChanged:\t" + s.toString());
        }
    });
```